# Print a 2-page document

Tags: vba, printing

I'm creating a program that has to print 2 pages, the first page me prints, the second page instead, which contains different information, I just can not program it. In practice, the program must create a single printable document consisting of 2 pages. Can you kindly help me?

I tried with HAS MORE PAGE but I just can't.

Comment: "_the first page me prints_" what does that mean?

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe try to macro-recording this manual process : activate page2, copy the cells need to be printed, paste in page1 on the cell location you need. Set the print area in page1. Stop the recording. Have a look at the recorded macro. After that you need to find out on how to make the range of the copied cells in page2 dynamic, not hard-coded selection as seen in the result of the recorded macro. Then after the print-out code, clear the paste result (from the copied range of page2) in page1.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning let me explain, my program creates 2 pages, the first contains a table and the second of business data. I'm programming a button with the print function to try to print both pages. I would hate to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't use answers to clarify/expand on your original question. Edit the question instead.